# Why do I get an UnauthorizedAccessException running Octopus Tentacle as an administrator via Chef?

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, windows-server-2012, octopus-deploy, winrm

I'm using Chef to configure a Windows 2012 Server (RTM), including installing the Octopus Tentacle service so I can then deploy software onto this instance using Octopus Deploy.

My workstation (the Chef client) is running Windows 7 x64 SP1. The server is hosted in VMware Workstation, and is running Windows 2012 Server x64 RTM. It's booted from a sysprepped baseline image, and everything's working really nicely until the Chef recipe tries to create a new Octopus certificate.

The octopus.rb Chef recipe wraps a chunk of Powershell, and the bit that actually does the Octopus Tentacle installation looks like this:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile("#{source_path_tanticle}", "#{install_path_tanticle}")
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /i, "#{install_path_tanticle}", /quiet -Wait  | out-file -filepath C:\\Octopus.log -append
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Octopus" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=#{tanticle_port}  | out-file -filepath C:\\Octopus.log -append

cd "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Octopus Tentacle\\Agent"
.\\tentacle.exe configure --appdir="C:\\Applications" --port=#{tanticle_port} --trust="#{octopus_server_Thumbprint}" | out-file -filepath C:\\Octopus.log -append
.\\tentacle.exe new-certificate | out-file -filepath C:\\Octopus.log -append
.\\tentacle.exe register-with --server=$octopusServer --publicHostname=$publicDnsName --environment=$environment --role=web --apikey=$octopusServerApiKey | out-file -filepath C:\\Octopus.log -append
```

When this script calls `tentacle.exe new-certificate` it's throwing an `UnauthorizedAccessException`:

```
Generating and installing a new cetificate...
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Octopus.Shared.Security.CertificateGenerator.Generate(String fullName, Boolean exportable) in c:\w\e6923628be6eaf72\source\Octopus.Shared\Security\CertificateGenerator.cs:line 25
   at Octopus.Tentacle.Commands.NewCertificateCommand.Execute() in c:\w\e6923628be6eaf72\source\Octopus.Tentacle\Commands\NewCertificateCommand.cs:line 31
   at Octopus.Shared.Startup.CommandProcessor.Process(String[] args) in c:\w\e6923628be6eaf72\source\Octopus.Shared\Startup\CommandProcessor.cs:line 40
```

The Chef client service is running as Administrator (at least, when I dump $env:username into the octopus.log file created during install, it says Administrator) so I'm not sure what file/folder/resource the Octopus tentacle is trying to access.

The actual Chef command being run to bootstrap the node is:

```
 knife bootstrap windows winrm 192.168.202.137 -x Administrator -P p@ssw0rd -r 'role[web_server]'
```

where 192.168.202.137 is the IP address of the newly-booted Win2012 server and p@ssw0rd is the local administrator password on that server.

Running the same commands manually on the server whilst logged in as Administrator works perfectly, so it's something to do with the chef/winrm/powershell remoting.

One theory is that I'm hitting some sort of DCOM/WinRM security edge case because I'm running different OSes on the client and server (Win7 x64 vs Win2012) - but given the invocation chain here is cmd.exe -> Ruby -> WinRM -> Ruby -> Powershell I'm a little lost as to how I would remedy, or even verify, such a problem...

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that when you invoke PowerShell over WinRM, the profile for the administrator user isn't being loaded? Can you force loading of the user profile?

Comment: Pretty much that appears to be what you need to do. I ended up fixing this using [mixlib-shellout](https://github.com/opscode/mixlib-shellout) to do "run as" stuff. In theory, this should also be doable with start-process/Process.Start, but that's ended up being a world of pain with Powershell and Chef

Answer (score 2):

Still not quite sure why this occurs, but working around it by getting [mixlib-shellout](https://github.com/opscode/mixlib-shellout) to do a psuedo-"run as" seems to work well. Note that this is still as exactly the same user, but somehow on Windows it appears you can be logged in as the user without actually being fully logged in as the user....

In theory, [start-process](http://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html) should be able to do the same thing (without the need for the user's password) but making that run reliably was a world of pain, and so for the moment we're sticking with mixlib-shellout.

Answer (score 1):

In case it's a permissions problem, try granting **Read and Enroll** and **Write** access to Everyone by using the Sites and Services snap-in for MMC. You can set the access rights on the Security tab by expanding the following items: Services, Public Key Services, Certificate Templates. Note that the Show Services Node check box must be selected on the View menu to see the Services tab.